# confirm card payment - async await issue on stripe

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs2, async-await, nuxt.js, stripe-payments

As you can see below I am using async await promise function below, so I expect the api call to '/stripe/update_shipping' take place first and then "$stripe.confirmCardPayment" to take place second, but for some reason in production, I see sometimes the charge taking place first and then the update_shipping taking place second.

Is this an issue on my end? or is it something that happens on Stripe?
How can I make sure confirm Card Payment is only called after payment intent is updated?

```
async processCardPayment() {

     this.stripeFailed = '';
     if ( this.validateCreditCardDetails() ) {

                // Updating Amount using Payment Intent api (data sent to backend)
                let updateShipping = await this.$axios.$post('/stripe/update_shipping', {
                    payment_id: this.paymentRef,
                    amount: this.total + this.shipping_options[this.shipping_option_selected].amount,
                });
                
                //charging customer
                this.$stripe.confirmCardPayment(
                    this.secret,
                    {payment_method: {
                        card: this.cardPaymentElement,
                        billing_details:    {
                            address:    {
                                line1: this.address.line1,
                                line2: this.address.line2,
                                city: this.address.post_town,
                                country: this.address.country,
                                postal_code: this.address.postcode,
                            },
                            name: this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name,
                            email: this.emailAddress,
                            phone: this.phoneNumber,
                        }
                    }},
                    {handleActions: false}
                ).then(function(confirmResult) {
                        if (result.error) {
                            // The payment failed
                            this.stripeFailed = 'Your payment failed to complete. ' + (result.error.message || '') ;
                        } else {
                            // The payment has succeeded.
                            this.uploadCardOrder();
                            this.processing_payment = false;
                        }
                 }.bind(this));
     }else {
         this.stripeFailed = 'Please complete the highlighted fields.' ;
         this.processing_payment = false;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put an `awaits` keyword in front of the `stripe.confirmCardPayment` to make the code execution sequential. So that `stripe.confirmCardPayment` will be called after the network request completes.

```
const { error, paymentIntent } = await $stripe.confirmCardPayment(...
if (error) {
...
} else {
...
}
```

Comment: I will test this and let you know.

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia also don't use `.then` it already using `async/await`. And highlight your code for better readability please.